# Cypress click on the drop-down element

Tags: cypress

please tell me how to click on this element marked in the picture[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [{force:true}](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click#Coordinates) `cy.get('elementSelector').click({force:true})`